# Transferring encrypted file using sockets and decrypting the file using DES and MD5

Tags: java, sockets, encryption, cryptography, des

I am doing a project in which data transfer should be secured. I am using password based encryption with MD5 and DES for encrypting the file. 

The class for encrypting the file:

```
public class FileEncryptor {    
    private static String filename;
    private static String password;
    private static FileInputStream inFile;
    private static FileOutputStream outFile;
    public static String tempFilename;
    public static File tempFile;

    public static File encryptFile(File f, String passkey) throws Exception {
        if(f.isDirectory()) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "file object is a directory");
            return null;
        }
        filename = f.getPath();
        password = passkey;     
        //Need to create a temporary file which is filled with the encrypted data.
        tempFilename = filename + ".des";
        tempFile = new File(tempFilename);      
        inFile = new FileInputStream(f);
        outFile = new FileOutputStream(tempFile);       
        // Use PBEKeySpec to create a key based on a password.
        // The password is passed as a character array.
        PBEKeySpec keySpec = new PBEKeySpec(password.toCharArray());
        SecretKeyFactory sKeyFac = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBEWithMD5AndDES");
        SecretKey sKey = sKeyFac.generateSecret(keySpec);       
        byte[] salt = new byte[8];
        Random rnd = new Random();
        rnd.nextBytes(salt);
        int iterations = 100;       
         //Create the parameter spec for this salt and iteration count
        PBEParameterSpec parameterSpec = new PBEParameterSpec(salt, iterations);
        //Create the cipher and initiate it for encryption
        Cipher c = Cipher.getInstance("PBEWithMD5AndDES");
        c.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, sKey, parameterSpec);

        //Need to write the salt into the file. It is required for decryption
        outFile.write(salt);

        //Read the file and encrypt its bytes
        byte[] input = new byte[64];
        int bytesRead;
        while((bytesRead = inFile.read(input)) != -1) {
            byte[] output = c.update(input, 0, bytesRead);
            if(output != null) { outFile.write(output); }           
        }

        byte[] output = c.doFinal();
        if(output != null) { outFile.write(output); }

        //Closing the streams before exiting.
        inFile.close();
        outFile.flush();
        outFile.close();

        return tempFile;
    }

}
```

The class for decrypting the file:

```
public class FileDecryptor {
 
    private static String filename;
    private static String password;
    private static FileInputStream inFile;
    private static FileOutputStream outFile;

    public static File decryptFile(File encryptedFile, String passkey) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, 
                                                            InvalidKeySpecException, IOException, NoSuchPaddingException,
                                                            InvalidKeyException, InvalidAlgorithmParameterException, IllegalBlockSizeException, BadPaddingException {

        String encryptedfilename = encryptedFile.getPath();
        password = passkey;

        inFile = new FileInputStream(encryptedFile);
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer(encryptedfilename);
        sb.reverse();
        sb.delete(0, 3);
        sb.reverse();           //removing the ".des" extension of the encrypted file
        filename = new String(sb) + ".dec";

        File decrypFile = new File(filename);
        outFile = new FileOutputStream(decrypFile);

        PBEKeySpec keySpec = new PBEKeySpec(password.toCharArray());
        SecretKeyFactory sKeyFac = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBEWithMD5AndDES");
        SecretKey sKey = sKeyFac.generateSecret(keySpec);

        // Read in the previously stored salt and set the iteration count.
        byte[] salt = new byte[8];
        inFile.read(salt);
        int iterations = 100;

        PBEParameterSpec parameterSpec = new PBEParameterSpec(salt, iterations);

        //Create the cipher and initialize it for decryption.
        Cipher c = Cipher.getInstance("PBEWithMD5AndDES");
        c.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, sKey, parameterSpec);

        byte[] input = new byte[64];
        int bytesRead;
        while((bytesRead = inFile.read(input)) != -1) {
            byte[] output = c.update(input, 0, bytesRead);
            if(output != null) {
                outFile.write(output);
            }
        }

        byte[] output = c.doFinal();
        System.out.println("Decrypted the data....");
        System.out.println("Wrting the data into file!!");
        if(output != null) {
            outFile.write(output);
        }
        System.out.println("Closing the streams");
        inFile.close();
        outFile.flush();
        outFile.close();

        return decrypFile;      
    }
}
```

Sending logic:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
       // TODO Auto-generated method stub
       Socket cs;
       OutputStream os;
       FileInputStream fis;
       byte[] b = new byte[6022386];
       File f = new File("D:\\abc.txt");
       File tempFile;

       try {
           tempFile = FileEncryptor.encryptFile(f, "impetus");
           fis = new FileInputStream(tempFile);
           ServerSocket ss = new ServerSocket(7007);
           System.out.println("Created and listening...");
           while(true) {
               System.out.println("Incoming connection!!!!!!!!");
               cs  = ss.accept();
               System.out.println("Client connected");
               os = cs.getOutputStream();
               fis.read(b);
               System.out.println("Sending the encrypted data");
               os.write(b);
           }
       } catch (Exception e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
       }
   }
```

Receiving logic:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
       // TODO Auto-generated method stub
       File f = new File("D:\\P2PFolder\\ToDec.txt.des");
       FileOutputStream fos;
       InputStream is;
       Socket s;
       int bytesRead = 0;
       int current = 0;
       byte[] rb = new byte[6022386];
       try {
           fos = new FileOutputStream(f);
           System.out.println("Connecting.....");
            s = new Socket(InetAddress.getLocalHost(), 7007);
            System.out.println("Connected!!!");
            is = s.getInputStream();
            do {
                System.out.println("Reading encrypted data from socket");
                bytesRead = is.read(rb, current, (rb.length - current));
                System.out.println(new String(rb) + bytesRead);
                if(bytesRead > 0) {
                    current += bytesRead;
                }
            } while(bytesRead > -1);
           fos.write(rb);
           is.close();
           fos.flush();
           fos.close();
           System.out.println("Decrypting the file");
           FileDecryptor.decryptFile(f, "impetus");
       } catch (Exception e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
       }
   }
```

No exceptions are being thrown but no data is being transferred also. The encryption part is done successfully. But the transferring and decryption are not happening. I checked the code for transferring the file without encryption, it is working. The encryption and decryption classes are also working when used separately without file transfer. Can someone please point out where am I going wrong here. I am sorry if the code is too long but had to present what I tried.

Comment: Fire up the debugger and you'll be wiser in an instant.

Comment: Are you communicating with somebody in the 70s, 80s or 90s? Because DES and MD5 have been deprecated *long ago*. You should definitely retake your stream handling tests. Sometimes you need a loop and closing a stream (try-with-resources) is also recommended.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes hahaha Sorry but its my college project.

Comment: No problem, but it seems your prof. is stuck in some kind of statis field in that case. I'm not sure why he would be teaching this kind of technology while there are more up to date techniques (that are as easy to learn) such as AES and PBKDF2.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes we proposed the project and since he accepted i have to complete project anyhow. We dug up grave for ourselves. :(

Answer (score 1):

1. You aren't closing `os` in the server, so the client copy loop never terminates.
2. When you fix that, you will discover the files are too big.

   ```
   fis.read(b);
   System.out.println("Sending the encrypted data");
   os.write(b);
   ```

The problem is that your two different copy processes are both wrong. The canonical way to copy streams in Java is as follows:

```
byte[] buffer = new byte[8192]; // or more
int count;
while ((count = in.read(buffer)) > 0)
{
    out.write(buffer, 0, count);
}
```

Use this at both ends. You don't need a buffer the size of the file, or bigger.

Comment: Thanks you so much . Hope it helps